# Why won't this events FQL statement return results?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to return events for a specific account. This a query that used to work but one morning decided not to. Pasting it into facebook's query console, I get all of the results but on my actual site it returns an empty array. Why?

```
SELECT
          eid, name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description 
        FROM
          event
        WHERE
          eid
           IN ( SELECT
                    eid
                  FROM
                    event_member
                  WHERE
                    uid = 256179217727449 ) 
            AND
              start_time > 1326725270
        ORDER BY
          start_time asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few reasons why this query would stop working.

1. The access token is expired
2. Your facebook app is disabled
3. Your event is gone
4. The uid is no longer active
5. Your access token is not setup for `user_events`
6. The start time has changed to before the time code specified
7. The uid is no longer a facebook user

My suggestion, try your FQL using the Graph API Explorer at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and add to your question the results it returns.

Comment: I never realised access tokens were added... This thing worked for a few months before it just stopped. So, yeah: I generated an access token and passed it in the $facebook->api() call. Thanks, DMCS.

Comment: I was wrong - now this access token has expired and I haven't figured out what the best way is to generate a new one. I've managed to do it through the tool you linked to, but I don't understand how to do this step programatically in PHP. Help?

Comment: See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.  There's lots of good examples in PHP on how to get your user to authenticate your app, getting you a new access token.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up generating an access token using the link you gave but with the offline option set, meaning the access token isn't supposed to expire. Thanks again.